# Google Fetch and Render for Wp hacked site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, google-search-console

I have a WP website, which got hacked. I cleaned the potential codes and uploaded the new version of the site,

But when I use Google to fetch and render, I'm seeing the home page as in the image:

[image]

Please suggest what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Guys found the solution, the bot code was injected in wp-load.php
Cleared and not its fine.